# Key travel on Thinkpad X201?

Tags: keyboard, lenovo-laptop, thinkpad

What is the official/known-measured key travel figure, in mm for the Thinkpad X201 laptop?

(I want to be able to understand how bad of a keyboard some of the newer laptops I'm considering, have)

Comment: You'll have a hard time searching for that since it's not something that's advertised (unless it's mechanic) and if the switches are proprietary there's little to no information of key travel.

Comment: @CaldeiraG: I know that laptop reviews occasionally mention key travel. And - you can supposedly measure it, I just don't know which key to use for the "offical" figure and from what reference line exactly do you make the measurement.

Comment: Isn’t it basically the same on all “semi-classic” ThinkPads?`

Comment: @DanielB: 1. I don't know 2. But, what is that same travel distance? :-(

Answer (score 1):

I have an x201, I measured the key travel at 100/1000th of an inch, or approximately 2.54mm